# Rails3 Default Scope Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to load a column from an existing database by renaming it using my model's default scope:

```
def self.default_scope
        Radcheck.find( :all,
       :select => ('attribute as newvalue')
       )
end
```

However, I still get an error stating attribute is defined....

I wish I could rename the column directly but it's referenced too much already. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, attribute is a reserved word. I know this isn't the answer you want to hear, but you really need to change the name of that column.

Comment: Hi, I'd love to but it's far to integrated.

Answer (score 0):

As `attribute` is not allowed. You may consider using [view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28database%29) to represent the column in the different name without effecting the existing reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the column as it is an SQL reserved word:

```
def self.default_scope
        Radcheck.find( :all,
       :select => "#{Radcheck.connection.quote_column_name('attribute')} AS newvalue"
       )
end
```

You could just use

```
       :select => '`attribute` AS newvalue'
```

but that is DB specific - which might or might not be a problem for you.